# Flask API authentication

Tags: authentication, flask, google-chrome-extension, flask-restful

I am building a chrome extension that sends GET requests to a flask API I've built. I want to add some sort of authentication to the API so that only my chrome extension can receive that data.

I have looked into using a JSON web token but it seems that by doing that, I would have to have the username and password in my chrome extension code, which is easily accessible to anyone once the chrome extension is published.

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store a JWT with such data as some constant in the chrome extension code.

JWTs should be generated dynamically in this use case; I recommend [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures) from Miguel.

I don't think, however, that this is the way to go. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192846/secure-access-to-api-only-from-chrome-extension). If you provide authentication (you know who your users are and they need to log in), then you can use those details to create a session based authentication or a JWT token approach (see Flask-Login, Flask-Security, Flask-Principal, Flask-JWT, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if my chrome extension doesn't have a login? I just want to display data to those who have the chrome extension downloaded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577110/securing-website-api-keys-in-chrome-extensions

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome! If this solves your question please mark it as solved!